# R: multiline shell command with embedded quotes

Tags: r, shell, powershell

Seems like this should be very simple, but I cannot get it to work. I have a long shell command that I would like to span over multiple lines, but escaping the single/double quotes correctly is giving me trouble. I have searched SO and googled this, but cannot find the solution.

Original, working code:

```
getVersion <- function() {
    version <- shell("powershell -Command $path = 'C:/Windows/notepad.exe'; $versioninfo = [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($path); $itemproperties= get-childitem $path; [pscustomobject]@{'File version' = $versioninfo.FileVersion}", intern = TRUE)
    version <- gsub(" ", "", version[4])
    return(version)
}
```

Does not work:

```
getVersion <- function() {
    version <- shell(paste0(\""powershell -Command $path = 'C:/Windows/notepad.exe'; $versioninfo = [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($path);\",
        \"$itemproperties= get-childitem $path; [pscustomobject]@{'File version' = $versioninfo.FileVersion}"\"), intern = TRUE)
    version <- gsub(" ", "", version[4])
    return(version)
}
```

Also tried this:

```
getVersion <- function() {
    version <- paste0('shell(\"powershell -Command $path = "C:/Windows/notepad.exe"; $versioninfo = [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($path);',
            '$itemproperties= get-childitem $path; [pscustomobject]@{"File version" = $versioninfo.FileVersion}\", intern = TRUE)')
            version <- gsub(" ", "", version[4])
            return(version)
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to escape?  You don't actually have double quotes in the string you need to pass, right?  So you can just do a paste() with double quoted strings that happen to contain single quotes.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: For example, would this work?

 `getVersion <- function() {
  version <- shell(paste("powershell -Command $path = 'C:/Windows/notepad.exe';",
                         "$versioninfo = [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($path);",
                         "$itemproperties= get-childitem $path;",
                         "[pscustomobject]@{'File version' = $versioninfo.FileVersion}"), intern = TRUE)
  version <- gsub(" ", "", version[4])
  return(version)
}`

Comment: Yes, that works. Thank you.

Comment: Cool, I'm going to post this as an answer, then, and you can mark it as the correct one, ok?

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you trying to escape? You don't actually have double quotes in the string you need to pass, right? So you can just do a paste() with double quoted strings that happen to contain single quotes. Or am I missing something?

For example, would this work?

```
getVersion <- function() { version <- shell(paste("powershell -Command $path = 'C:/Windows/notepad.exe';", 
"$versioninfo = [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($path);‌​", 
"$itemproperties= get-childitem $path;", 
"[pscustomobject]@{'File version' = $versioninfo.FileVersion}"), 
intern = TRUE) 
version <- gsub(" ", "", version[4])
return(version) }
```

Comment: I formatted the code from your comment a bit differently, but it seems to work just the same.